# Is there possible conflict between Boostrap JS bundle and AJAX?

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-4

So I have my jquery scripts as below. But for some reason the jquery doesn't work for my Bootstrap. It works fine when I delete the ajax part, but it's necessary for my Django app. Is the order problem? Or am I using the wrong bundles? Thanks in advance :)

```
...
    <!-- Bootstrap4 CDN -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- JS bundle for Bootstrap4 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- for AJAX -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No conflict (only if you use jQuery)
Sometimes it is necessary to use Bootstrap plugins with other UI frameworks. In these circumstances, namespace collisions can occasionally occur. If this happens, you may call .noConflict on the plugin you wish to revert the value of.

```
var bootstrapButton = $.fn.button.noConflict() // return $.fn.button to previously assigned value
$.fn.bootstrapBtn = bootstrapButton // give $().bootstrapBtn the Bootstrap functionality
```

and also, The $.ajax is not a function error is normally because you're using the slim branch of jQuery, not the full version. Remove that slim reference and use only a single copy of jquery-3.5.1.min.js